# Geocoder Nearby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geocode

I'm a beginner in Rails.

I implemented the Geocoder gem and added latitude/longitude columns to a table named 'adventure'.

I added

```
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
```

to my model adventures.rb

I now try to render a list of 3 nearby places by applying the following:

```
 <% for adventure in @adventure.nearbys(2).limit(3) %>
```

but it does not work and tells me "undefined method `limit' for nil:NilClass".

It's weird because I follow a tutorial in which things work.

What did I miss ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Link to tutorial?
Also, the nearbys() method is returning nil, so trying to run the limit method returns that error.

Comment: Jumping into the [source](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/bab2e367880b02505dea077951bfada987e2c93d/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb#L289) it looks like the only way nearbys returns nil is if the current object hasn't properly been geocoded. Can you make sure that your @adventure is geocoded?

Comment: @MatthewStevenson first thing, the table name should be adventures and model name `Adventure`, second thing if latitude and longitude stored correctly for record ? if its geocoded correctly then there should be no error. can you please add the source of tutorial in question ?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for your answers, sorry for the delay if thought I was receiving notifications from Stack for every answer ;)

Comment: The tutorial is in French and it has been deleted unfortunately, I'm trying to rewrite the same code that I wrote during the tutorial (it was a recode of Airbnb). Nevermind : how can I make sure that @adventure is geocoded ? I already added : geocoded_by :address

Comment: What is weird is that I also implemented GoogleMaps (which calls @adventure.latitude and @adventure.longitude) to render the address of the adventure, and I have no problem.